Evaluation of LLM on Classification Tasks
currently I'm doing research on my training method and dataset for LLMs on classification tasks. What i'm wondering right now is how to properly evaluate the model for classification tasks
When I load the model from huggingface with AutoModelForClassification, it will attach a classification head at the end of the model but the weight is initialized randomly and it also log that I have to train for the classification tasks.
What I'm thinking right now is freezing the backbone model with requires_grad = False and then just training the linear layer for classification tasks. I'm not sure it's legit to do this or not and if it's legit, how many epoch should I train the classification head on?
And to achieve the fine-tuned model, I will unfreeze the model and train the whole model (backbone + trained cls head). Is this method right or legit?
Thanks a lot.
